# Javascript assign array value to text

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

Can anyone show me how to output array value into different place.

Eg:

```
var list = [1,2,3]

textbox1 = 2
textbox2 = 1
textbox3 = 3
```

its shuffle array

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: what you really want to output?

Comment: list[0] will output 1, list[1] will output 2.....so on

Comment: I think you just answered your own question, `list[0]` will output `1`, `list[1]` will output `2`, etc.

Comment: I want to assign the value of the array to different textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex !== 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var list = [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]

var shuffle_list = shuffle(list);

text1 = shuffle_list[0]; //2
text2 = shuffle_list[1]; //1
text3 = shuffle_list[2]; //3
```

Try this, you can shuffle array use shuffle function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var original = [1, 2, 3]
var original_length = original.length

var randomShuffle = function(){
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * original.length)
    var number = original[idx]
    original.splice(idx, 1)
    return number
}

for (x = 0; x < original_length; x++){
    var name = "textbox" + (x + 1)
    eval("var " + name + " = " + randomShuffle())
}
console.log(textbox1, textbox2, textbox3)
```

This will dynamically generate your variables while randomly assigning them a value from the original array

https://repl.it/CdX5